# local vol model and stochastic vol model for double knock out barrier option

Tags: options, barrier

Here is an interview question:

> For a double knock out barrier option (ITM), which model gives higher price? local vol or stochastic vol model?

The answer is that local vol gives the higher price. However I only know that stochastic vol is the correct model to price barrier option to control the forward vol (vol of vol) as the product depends on the conditional distribution.

Comment: And what is the question you are asking ?

Answer (score 1):

Empirically, knock-out barrier options are more expensive in stochastic volatility models and less expensive in local volatility models. Since knock-out + knock-in = vanilla, and vanillas are priced the same in local vs stochastic volatility, knock-in barrier options are priced higher in local volatility.

There is no known mathematical proof for this, and I have seen rare claimed counterexamples. But it is certainly true almost always.